# Spectral Linting to Check for a Tag Being Present

Tags: lint, spectral

How can I check for tags being present? I can check for tags having values. For example,

```
paths[*]..summary
```

shows me the value of the summary tags that are present:

```
[
  "List all pets",
  "Create a pet",
  "Info for a specific pet"
]
```

But I want to check if the summary tag itself is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jakub Rożek:

```
rules:
  summary-tag-defined:
    given: $.paths[*][get,post,put,delete,patch,trace,options,head]
    then:
      field: summary
      function: defined
```